# javascript onload image !complete

Tags: javascript

In Firefox 8.0 on ubuntu 11.10, the onload function, `draw`, is called although `img.complete` is false. I managed to solve it somewhat with the `setTimeout` hack, but it's not pretty.
I tried setting the `img.onload` before setting `img.src`. Although I always get `img.complete` as true this way, `img.width` is zero, and `img.src` si also empty, so it doesn't work.
Any ideas how to implement this properly?

```
        var draw=function(img,ctx,x,y)
        { if(!img.complete)
            {   setTimeout(function(){draw(img,ctx,x,y);},50);
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.drawImage(img,x,y); 
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {   img=new Image();
            img.src="/media/"+url[i];
            img.onload=(draw)(img,ctx,tile.x*offset[i].x,tile.y*offset[i].y);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `complete` property is buggy in Firefox. Once it's `true`, it's *always* `true` (even if you change the image).

I got around it by testing a new `Image` object.

Answer (score -1):

new Image for every .complete doesn't work, either.

Try checking img.width for greater than zero instead.